# GraphQL some params in where query

Tags: graphql, strapi

How to create a query with some parameters in the part where of GraphQL query.

I have query with one parameter and I need to add some parameters to that query.

```
query{
  places(where:{longitude_gte:21.00}){
    latitude
    location
    name
    phoneNumber
  }
}
```

Comment: implementation specific - see API docs

Comment: non int needs  quotation marks in json ...  `places(where:{longitude_gte:"21.00"}){`

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
restaurants(where:{name_contains:["McD","King"],id_gt:5})
```

Gives you restaurants, which name contains ”McD” or ”King” AND which id is greater than ”5”